# Which API joomla 3 return menus and submenu for site that created by admin?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-api, menu

I want to create a **Joomla menu** from  **scratch** **myself**!
I studied a bit about the Joomla API, I know I should use **Jmenu**,but when I use:

```
   <?php $M=Jmenu::load();
    echo $M;?>
```

it returns some errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\templates\mymagazine4\index.php on line 7
>   Array

or **print nothing**.

this is link Jmenu [Jmenu](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JMenu.html) -
How should I use it to show a menu???

thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get instance of menu:

```
$menu = JMenu::getInstance('site'); // or 'administrator' for back-end
```

this will load all items for you.

**Now you can:**

1. Get all menu items

   `$allMenuItems = $menu->getItems($attributes = array(), $values = array());`
2. Get default item (homepage)

   `$defaultMenuItem = $menu->getDefault($language = '*');`

To print your menu links, start with this:

```
$menu = JMenu::getInstance('site');
$allMenuItems = $menu->getItems($attributes = array(), $values = array());
if (count($allMenuItems)>0) {
  foreach ($allMenuItems as $menuItem) {
    echo '<a href="'.JRoute::_($menuItem->link).'">'.$menuItem->title.'</a>';
  }
} else {
  echo 'No menu items.';
}
```

Comment: when i use $menu=.... it is show any thing.

Comment: when i use echo $menu,it has error  Catchable fatal error: Object of class JMenuSite could not be converted to string in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\templates\mymagazine4\index.php on line 7

Comment: i write these code in html folder my template >mod_menu>index.php

Comment: You can't `echo` PHP `object`. What are you trying to do? To get items, use `$allMenuItems = $menu->getItems();print_r($allMenuItems);` and you will see array of all menu items. Then you should iterate over eeach one and echo you links.

Comment: i wanted echo menu for showing in html file.

Comment: i use now   <?php
//$Jtemp= JMenu::getInstance(1, 1);
//echo $Jtemp;
$menu = JMenu::getInstance('site');
$allMenuItems = $menu->getItems();// or 'administrator' for back-end
print_r($allMenuItems); 
?> it has errors!                         
Warning: Missing argument 1 for JMenuSite::getItems(), called in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\templates\mymagazine4\index.php on line 7 and defined in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\libraries\cms\menu\site.php on line 89

Warning: Missing argument 2 for JMenuSite::getItems(), called in

Comment: I added example for printing menu items.

Comment: it test final example my menu is show thanks but it ha warning 
Warning: Missing argument 1 for JMenuSite::getItems(), called in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\templates\mymagazine4\index.php on line 7 and defined in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\libraries\cms\menu\site.php on line 89

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: attributes in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\libraries\cms\menu\site.php on line 91

Notice: Undefined variable: values in K:\xampp\htdocs\mag2\libraries\cms\menu\site.php on line 92

Comment: i went class,i  will soon comeback and  i  will explain my  error

Comment: I edited my code. Which these `$attributes` and `$values` you can basically get certain menu items (by language, access level) etc.

Comment: @ Rene Korss  you are best,my problem is solved.thanks very much